# PNG image not rendering correctly

Tags: animation

I am new to Blender. I have completed my **2d** animation and when I render it everything works smoothly. The last thing I want to do is put a background behind it. The background is a PNG image and when I import it into Blender it looks perfect. However, when I go to render my animation the background image is dark and sometimes just a gray box. Could someone please help me out? Please note that this is a 2d animation (if that makes a difference).

Secondly, I'm not quite sure how to add my files to this forum for you to look at. If you could let me know, I'd gladly add them.

Comment: please add images of your compsiting nodes and some image that exemplifies the issue you are having. It's hard to guess otherwise.

Comment: Along with adding images, if you do add your file, you can upload it to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ (please pack textures and include only the necessary elements) and [edit](http://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/77419/edit) the provided link into your question.